# Print nanoseconds in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh, unix-timestamp

I need to print nanoseconds or milliseconds time in Unix command line.
In bash flovour there is %N, however korn shell does not print nanoseconds if that is used.How to print that Unix time with nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1):

For the ksh, we do have

> date

command. You can try the below:

%s%N will give you seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC concatenated with nanoseconds.

```
date +%s%N
```

Below will return concated result of hh:min:ss and nanoseconds.

```
date +%T%N
```

To extract nanosecods use

```
echo "nanoseconds:"$(($(date +%s%N)%1000000000))
```

To extract miliseconds use

```
echo "miliseconds:"$(($(date +%s%3N)%1000))
```